# Always increasing condition of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

In a classroom I was told today that the function is always increasing if $f'(X)\ge0$.

Interestingly my teacher took a function as $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x+5$ which is always increasing although at $x=-1$, derivative will be zero.

Now this equal to zero disturbed me a lot. Suppose there is a function which is increasing and then for some continuous interval it gets constant and after that interval it again starts increasing.

Now $f'(x)\ge0$ will be satisfied in such a case, but is such a function always increasing, obviously its no.

I tried to google it but couldn't find such a case.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion between a function $f$ being considered to *just* be "increasing", which means $f(x) \ge f(y)$ if $x \gt y$, and it being "*strictly* increasing", which means $f(x) \gt f(y)$ if $x \gt y$.

In your case, you're correct the function $f$ is not necessarily "strictly increasing" (e.g., if $f(x) = c$, with $c$ being a constant, then $f'(x) \ge 0$ but $f$ is not strictly increasing). Note that $f'(x) \ge 0$ only guarantees the function is "increasing". I believe this is what your teacher meant (but I'm not quite sure what was meant by "always"), even though their example of $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 5$ is actually strictly increasing. It's also possible they meant strictly increasing and made a mistake by not stating $f'(x) \gt 0$ instead. To be completely certain, I suggest you ask your teacher to clarify.

Comment: ok but if you see the example of the function which I have given , in that case derivative is zero at $x=-1$, but still the function is strictly increasing, how is that possible. Yes by increasing I mean strictly increasing.

Comment: @user3290550 You could have that $f'(x) \ge 0$, with it being $0$ at some points, but the function is still strictly increasing, as with the example you mentioned, but this doesn't have to be the case. For example, if $f(x) = c$, with $c$ a constant, then obviously $f'(x) \ge 0$ but $f$ is not strictly increasing. With the particular function you mentioned, this is because the point is an [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point), similar to $f(x) = x^3$ having $f'(0) = 0$ but the function is still strictly increasing as well.

Comment: In particular, $f'(x) > 0$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for a function to be strictly increasing. $f'(x) \geq 0$ is a necessary, but not sufficient condition. In general, we want $f'(x) \geq 0$ and the set of $f'(x) = 0$ to be isolated.

Comment: can there be multiple points in a function where its derivative is zero and still it is strictly increasing.

Comment: @user3290550 Yes, a function can have a derivative be $0$ a multiple points but still be strictly increasing. I don't know offhand of any "simple" (i.e., expressed in terms of closed-form functions) function which exhibits this. However, I also recall basically what The Great Duck wrote, i.e., this occurs when the set of points is "discrete" (I believe more generally it's when they have measure $0$).

Comment: so you mean to say that distance between such points should not be zero?

Comment: @user3290550 As I've added to the end of my answer, possibly the teacher meant that it's strictly increasing, but made a mistake of not writing $f'(x) \gt 0$. Since I don't know what the teacher's intent was, and can only at best guess, I suggest you ask to confirm what it might be.

Comment: if $f'(x)>=0$, we can't say that function is strictly increasing. So in that case is there any way to determine if the function is strictly increasing or not.

Comment: @user3290550 As far as I know, the only fool-proof way to prove a function $f$ where $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ is strictly increasing is to use the definition, i.e., prove that for any $x \gt y$ that $f(x) \gt f(y)$. There might be some ways to use various higher derivatives, if they exist, but I don't know offhand exactly what that would be. However, even if you could use these derivatives, or some other method, it's most likely more complicated and difficult than just proving what I stated, i.e., $f(x) \gt f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote: "can there be multiple points in a function where its derivative is zero and still it is strictly increasing."

For the function $f(x) = x + \sin x,$ we have $f'(x) = 1 + \cos x,$ and this is $0$ at every odd multiple of $\pi,$ and yet the function is strictly increasing.

If $f'=0$ at an isolated point and $f'>0$ at every point in some open interval containing that point, then $f$ is strictly increasing on that interval. You can see that by drawing a picture.

Remeber that $\text{“}$strictly increasing$\text{''}$ is equivalent to saying the slope of every **secant** line is positive.

Comment: but how to know that if the derivative is coming at zero at certain points, then function is strictly increasing or not.

Comment: @user3290550 : Suppose $a<b$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$ and $f'>0$ everywhere between $a$ and $b.$ The the mean value theorem implies that the slope of the secant line between $a$ and $b$ is positive. Now suppose $a<b<c$ and $f'(b)=0$ and $f'>0$ everywhere between $a$ and $b$ except at $c.$ Then the secant line between $a$ and $b$ has positive slope and that between $b$ and $c$ has positive slope, and slopes of other secant lines are more easily shown to be positive.